# Is it possible to integrate Power BI with my website which is using Apache Tomcat server?

Tags: apache, tomcat, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I created reports in Power BI and I need to use that reports to visible on my website for the users.I googled it that we can integrate with Azure. Likewise
Is it a way to use it in Apache Tomcat Server?. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can to go for the publish to web feature of Power BI Service.

Using publish to web feature you will get an embed url which you can use embed report to your website. Only is downside using this embed url anyone can view your report. Publish to web doesn't provides any authentication mechanism.

Comment: Well, I needed to integrate Power BI Reports with my website rather than embedding. @Rajendra

Comment: If you want to integrate Power BI Reports to your web application you can go for Power BI Embedded which is Azure offering.